# Service account not respecting its cluster role

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rbac, kube-apiserver

*I created a context with a user that has **only READ access** but when I logged in as this user I can still do whatever I want like deploying and killing pods, etc... Why is that ?*

---

I followed this [tutorial](https://blog.zwindler.fr/2018/10/16/configurer-ses-contextes-pour-kubectl-sur-un-poste-client/).

1) First I created a service account:
`kubectl create sa myserviceaccount`

2) Now I wan a role with the minimum permission (**just READ**) so I'll take one from the kube-system called "**view**"

```
 $ kubectl describe clusterrole view
  Resources                                Non-Resource URLs  Resource Names  Verbs
  ---------                                -----------------  --------------  -----
  bindings                                 []                 []              [get list watch]
  configmaps                               []                 []              [get list watch]
  [...]
```

3) Now I must create a clusterRoleBinding to bind the service account to the role "view"

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: crbmyserviceaccount
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: myserviceaccount
  namespace: default
```

4) Now we must find the associated secret name

```
kubectl get secrets -> myserviceaccount-token-bmwwd
```

5) Save the displayed token somewhere (to be used later)

```
kubectl describe secret myserviceaccount-token-xxxxx
```

---

*Now that we have everything we need we can go on a kubernetes client and create the context.*

6) Configuring the cluster in kubeconfig :
`kubectl config set-cluster myawesomecluster --server=IP-OF-MY-CLUSTER`

7) Creating the credentials:

```
kubectl config set-credentials myawesomecluster-myserviceaccount --token=TOKEN-FROM-STEP-5
```

8) Creating the context

```
kubectl config set-context myawesomecluster --cluster=myawesomecluster --user=myawesomecluster-myserviceaccount --namespace=default
kubectl config use-context myawesomecluster
```

Taaddaaaa !

Now that the context is set I should be able to READ every ressources but **not** create any. Unfortunatly I can still make deployments using kubectl or even delete pods etc

**This should return me an access denied:** `kubectl create -f someFileWithDeployment`

What am I doing wrong ?
Thx !

---

**Edit - Adding output of namespaces and config view for debugging purpose :**

```
$kubectl get sa
NAME               SECRETS   AGE
api-explorer       1         39h
default            1         5d22h
myserviceaccount   1         17h


$kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /home/xxxx/rbac/accountTest/api-            explorer/context/team-a-decoded.crt
    server: http://127.0.0.1:8080
  name: cfc
- cluster:
    server: http://127.0.0.1:8080
  name: myawesomecluster
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: http://localhost:8080
  name: test-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cfc
    user: user
  name: cfc
- context:
    cluster: ""
    user: ""
  name: default
- context:
    cluster: myawesomecluster
    namespace: default
    user: myawesomecluster-myserviceaccount
  name: myawesomecluster
current-context: myawesomecluster
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: api-explorer
  user:
    token: ZXlKaGJHY2l[...]
- name: myawesomecluster-myserviceaccount
  user:
    token: eyJhbGci [...]
- name: user
  user:
    token: ZXlKaGJH
```

---

**Edit 2 : Showing output of get pod kube-apiserver-nodemaster1**

```
$kubectl get pod kube-apiserver-nodemaster1 -n kube-system -o yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/config.hash: 034c3[...]
    kubernetes.io/config.mirror: 034b3[...]
    kubernetes.io/config.seen: 2018-11-23T09:48:59.766423346Z
    kubernetes.io/config.source: file
    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ""
  creationTimestamp: 2018-11-23T09:50:29Z
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver-nodemaster1
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "804213"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-apiserver-nodemaster1
  uid: 36340f[...]
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --apiserver-count=3
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --bind-address=0.0.0.0
    - --endpoint-reconciler-type=lease
    - --insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1
    - --insecure-port=8080
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalDNS,InternalIP,Hostname,ExternalDNS,ExternalIP
    - --runtime-config=admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1
    - --service-node-port-range=30000-32767
    - --storage-backend=etcd3
    - --advertise-address=10.10.10.101
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/etcd/ca.pem
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/etcd/node-nodemaster1.pem
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/etcd/node-nodemaster1-key.pem
    - --etcd-servers=https://10.10.10.101:2379,https://10.10.10.102:2379,https://10.10.10.103:2379
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-client.key
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --secure-port=6443
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/sa.pub
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.233.0.0/18
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.key
    image: gcr.io/google-containers/kube-apiserver:v1.12.2
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 10.10.10.101
        path: /healthz
        port: 6443
        scheme: HTTPS
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: kube-apiserver
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 250m
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
      name: k8s-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: ca-certs
      readOnly: true
    - mountPath: /etc/pki
      name: etc-pki
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  hostNetwork: true
  nodeName: nodemaster1
  priority: 2000000000
  priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    operator: Exists
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes/ssl
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: k8s-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/certs
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: ca-certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/pki
      type: DirectoryOrCreate
    name: etc-pki
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2018-11-23T09:55:05Z
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2018-11-23T09:55:05Z
    status: "True"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2018-11-23T09:55:05Z
    status: "True"
    type: ContainersReady
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: 2018-11-23T09:55:05Z
    status: "True"
    type: PodScheduled
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://8287[...]
    image: gcr.io/google-containers/kube-apiserver:v1.12.2
    imageID: docker-pullable://gcr.io/google-containers/kube-apiserver@sha256:0949[...]
    lastState:
      terminated:
        containerID: docker://e97[...]
        exitCode: 0
        finishedAt: 2018-11-27T14:18:24Z
        reason: Completed
        startedAt: 2018-11-23T09:49:00Z
    name: kube-apiserver
    ready: true
    restartCount: 1
    state:
      running:
        startedAt: 2018-11-27T14:18:24Z
  hostIP: 10.10.10.101
  phase: Running
  podIP: 10.10.10.101
  qosClass: Burstable
  startTime: 2018-11-23T09:55:05Z
```

Comment: can you give your output for `$ kubectl get sa` and `$ kubectl config view`?

Comment: I presume `kubectl create ns myserviceaccount` is a typo in this question body, or did you really type that command? And, just for clarity, you _do_ have `--authorization-mode=RBAC` on all your apiserver command lines, right?

Comment: @ShudiptaSharma Sorry for the late answer. I edited my question to add the data you asked!

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel Thx for your answer. You are totaly right It was a typo. I edited my answer. Now about the RBAC mode I did boot the server with the RBAC mode on... Should I add the  --authorization-mode option to all the cmd lines I did ?

Comment: @Doctor, Can you share `kube-apiserver` parameters via command `kubectl get pod kube-apiserver-<pod-name> -n kube-system -o yaml`?

Comment: @mk_sta I added the requested output to the question :-)

Comment: @Doctor - what do you see when executing `kubectl config current-context` just before executing `kubectl create -f someFileWithDeployment`?
Also, what's the result from `kubectl -n <namespace-here> auth can-i create deployment`...assuming "someFileWithDeployment" attempts to create a deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume when you use `--insecure-bind-address=127.0.0.1` and `--insecure-port=8080` flags in `kube-apiserver` configuration, all requests to Kubernetes API server bypass RBAC module authorization, as described in official Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/controlling-access/#api-server-ports-and-ips):

> **Localhost Port:**
>
> - is intended for testing and bootstrap, and for other components of    the master node (scheduler, controller-manager) to talk to the API
> - no TLS
> - default is port 8080, change with `--insecure-port` flag.
> - default IP is localhost, change with `--insecure-bind-address` flag.
> - request **bypasses** authentication and authorization modules.
> - request handled by admission control module(s).
> - protected by need to have host access

Comment: Thx for your answer. You are completely right ! I was minutes ago to answer myself but you beat me to it ! So in step 6) now I stopped using the http://localhost:8080 but replaced it with the secure port https://localhost:6443. There's also a specific manipulation to use the service account as context.
I'll accept your answer and create one of my own to get in more details for future users.

Answer (score 1):

As @mk_sta explained I had to use the HTTPS endpoint and not the default http one.
Http endpoint is considered for deprecation and will probably be removed as explained [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/53077#issuecomment-340897992)

In order to go through the https endpoint replace step 6 :

```
kubectl config set-cluster myawesomecluster --server=https://127.0.0.1:6443
```

Now you will probably have an SLL error.
What I did is change my kubeconfig file (in ~/.kube/config).
I added the key **"certificate-authority"** with the value of the **path where kubernetes stores its master certificate**.
The final cluster config looks like this now :

```
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt
    server: https://127.0.0.1:6443
  name: secureRemote
```